# JS/Nodejs can't access quoted index of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, indexing

I use babyparse (PapaParse) in nodejs to process csv to javascript objects.

One object output is as follows:

```
{ 'ProductName': 'Nike t-shirt',
   ProductPrice: '14.99',
   ProductPriceOld: '39.99' }
```

You can see that somehow the first index is quoted ('ProductName').
I can't manage to access this value. I have tried:

```
console.log(product['ProductName'])
console.log(product["\'ProductName\'"])
console.log(product['\'ProductName\''])
console.log(product.ProductName)
```

This all results in 'undefined'. product.ProductPrice or product['ProductPrice'] gives me the correct value.

Any idea what can be causing this, and how to solve it?

Edit: if I JSON.stringify(product) the single quotes are gone, but if I JSON.parse(json) into the object, the single quotes return..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that the property name is expressed as a string instead of an identifier in the output is that the name includes characters which aren't allowed in an identifier.

Specifically, the first character is: *U+FEFF : ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE [ZWNBSP] (alias BYTE ORDER MARK [BOM])*.

You need to include that in the property name when you access it.

```
product["\uFEFFProductName"]
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the unprintable character - now that you pointed it out it's obvious. ;) Plus one and I'm removing my answer.

Comment: Thanks, would have never figured this out myself. I use body = body.replace(/\uFEFF/g, '') to remove this from my input, now the processing works perfectly.